# How to prepare month by month time series data in R from aggregated data containing part wise sales vs month?

Tags: dataframe, time-series, data-science, data-cleaning, forecasting

I am having a dataframe which consists of month wise sales data for many parts:
For eg

Partno   Month      Qty

Part 1   June 2019    20

Part 1   July 2019     25

Part 1   Sep  2019    30

Part 2   Mar  2019    45

Part 3   Aug  2019   40

Part 3   Nov  2019   21

I want to convert this data into a month by month time series, which makes it easier for time series forecasting, Once I make it into a ts object

Month   Part1   Part 2  Part 3

Jan        0    0         0

Feb        0    0         0

Mar        0    45        0

Apr        0    0         0

May        0    0         0

June       20   0         0

July       25   0         0

Aug         0   0         0

Sept        0   30        0

Oct         0    0        20

Nov         0     0       21

Dec         0      0       0

I am quite baffled as to how this can be carried out in R. Any solutions for the same would be highly useful, as I plan build some forecasting models in R.

Looking forward to hearing from you all!

Comment: Pictures of text are less helpful. Please undo your last edit and follow the path of appropriate formatting as outlined by a helpful user in the preceeding edit.

Comment: Can some one help me do this? I am new to stack overflow.

Comment: Please read the instructions at the top of the [tag:r] tag on how to ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

Assume the data `DF` shown reproducibly in the Note at the end.

First convert `DF` to zoo splitting it by the first column and converting the Month column to yearmon class.  Then convert that to ts class, extend it to Jan to Dec, and set any NAs to 0.  (If you don't need the 0 months at the beginning and end omit the `yrs` and `window` lines.)

```
library(zoo)

z <- read.zoo(DF, split = 1, index = 2, FUN = as.yearmon, format = "%b %Y")
tt <- as.ts(z)
yrs <- as.integer(range(time(tt))) # start and end years
tt <- window(tt, start = yrs[1], end = yrs[2] + 11/12, extend = TRUE)
tt[is.na(tt)] <- 0
tt
```

giving:

```
         Part 1 Part 2 Part 3
Jan 2019      0      0      0
Feb 2019      0      0      0
Mar 2019      0     45      0
Apr 2019      0     20      0
May 2019      0      0      0
Jun 2019     20      0      0
Jul 2019     25      0      0
Aug 2019      0      0      0
Sep 2019     30      0      0
Oct 2019      0      0     20
Nov 2019      0      0     21
Dec 2019      0      0      0
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "Partno, Month, Qty
Part 1, Jun 2019, 20
Part 1, Jul 2019, 25
Part 1, Sep 2019, 30
Part 2, Mar 2019, 45
Part 2, Apr 2019, 20
Part 3, Oct 2019, 20
Part 3, Nov 2019, 21"
DF <- read.csv(text = Lines, strip.white = TRUE)
```

Comment: In my case, I already have a dataframe with quantity in numeric format, month in as.yearmon format

Comment: My data is not all text- qty is of double, partno is integer, month is of character. The months are not unique- we can even have April-2019 for both part 1 and part2. I had just asked to explain an example !

Comment: The input to the answer is DF.  Lines was just so we could define it.  You can have the same month in two different parts.  You can't have the same month twice in the same part though unless you add an aggregate= argument to read.zoo.

Comment: Thank you so much- it works now-I had already carried out the aggregate function separately . I'l keep in mind the aggregate arguement part in read.zoo for simplyfying the code lines next time.Also, i understand from your code that typeof(DF)  reveals that its a list. I had to convert my dataframe into a list for the same. I tried read.zoo with dataframe, but it didn;t work. Are there alternatives for reading dataframes and csv files directly and performing zoo function- I figured out read.csv.zoo() but I m having some errors - need to look into it

Comment: `DF` is a data frame.  Try `class(DF)`.  Every data frame is also a list but that is not relevant here.  `read.zoo` can read a file or a data frame. It does  not read lists which are not data frames.

Comment: Thank you. Wll Check it out. Yeah. It comes back to me- I understand it now..It's been quite a while since I read R Basics and fell out of touch much till now !

Comment: I have a question- Suppose I have aggregated the first table on a week basis and want to convert the time series to a weekly one, What do I do?

Comment: It really depends on precisely what you want to do.  If you remove the last day of each year (last two days in leap year) you could create an annual series with frequency 52.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64960531/converting-zoo-object-into-a-weekly-time-series I have posted my question in a separate query. Looking forward to your answer.